# Decorator to modify a generator value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class and each method of this class yields a dictionary. I want to create a decorator, which adds current date and time to the dictionary, which is yielded from a method. I've already implemented function-based solution, so it looks like this:

```
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import datetime


def _concat_datetime(func):
    def wrapper():
        for document in func():
            yield {
                **document,
                "current_date": datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                "current_time": datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
            }
    yield from wrapper()



@_concat_datetime 
def test():
    yield {
        "a": "a",
        "b": "b",
        "c": "c"
    }
for doc in test:
    pprint(doc)
```

Output:

`{
'a': 'a',
'b': 'b',
'c': 'c',
'current_date': '2019-11-19',
'current_time': '15:35:31'
}`

However, using class-based solution, I'm getting a conflict, connected with `self` keyword. I figured out, that I need to pass `self` to `wrapper()`. But I don't understand where to get it.

Class-based solution:

```
class TestClass:

    def _concat_datetime(func):
        def wrapper(self):
            for document in func(self):
                yield {
                    **document,
                    "current_date": datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                    "current_time": datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
                }
        yield from wrapper()


    @_concat_datetime
    def test(self):
        yield {
            "a": "a",
            "b": "b",
            "c": "c"
        }


obj = TestClass()

for doc in obj.test:
    pprint(doc)
```

Thank you so much in advance for checking this post out and all the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand everything correctly, but I feel you just need to return the decorated method instead of returning the generator. By the same occasion you can use a test function that yield several dictionaries:

```py
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import datetime

class TestClass:

    def _concat_datetime(func):
        def wrapper(self):
            for document in func(self):
                yield {
                    **document,
                    "current_date": datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                    "current_time": datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
                }
        return wrapper


    @_concat_datetime
    def test(self):
        yield dict(enumerate(["a", "b", "c"]))
        yield dict(enumerate(["d", "e", "f"]))


obj = TestClass()

for doc in obj.test():
    pprint(doc)
```

Which prints

```
{0: 'a',
 1: 'b',
 2: 'c',
 'current_date': '2019-11-19',
 'current_time': '15:01:07'}
{0: 'd',
 1: 'e',
 2: 'f',
 'current_date': '2019-11-19',
 'current_time': '15:01:07'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return the generator function, rather than yielding from a generator.

```
class TestClass:

    def _concat_datetime(func):
        def wrapper(self):
            for document in func(self):
                yield {
                    **document,
                    "current_date": datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                    "current_time": datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
                }
        return wrapper


    @_concat_datetime
    def test(self):
        yield {
            "a": "a",
            "b": "b",
            "c": "c"
        }
```